# Limit on both inside and the range of an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{kn}e^{tx}\frac{1}{k}\left ( 1- \frac{x}{kn}\right )^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Can I first show $$\frac{1}{k}\left ( 1- \frac{x}{kn}\right )^{n-1}$$ converges on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ to $ \frac{1}{k} \exp\left ( {-\frac{x}{k}} \right ) $ and evaluate the integral as an improper integral?

Comment: Do you mean to take the limit as $n \to \infty
$?

Comment: oh, yes! and it has been corrected now! thx

Comment: Looks like you found a majorant function. Lebesgue's Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) would then apply, provided you consider the improper integral separately from the integrand.